# Read string from a combined string Help how to read this

Tags: android, string

i want to read this string

```
 String  "abc;def;ghi;jklm;nopqr"
```

i want to get these diffrent diffrent

```
  string a = abc;
  string b = def;
      string c = ghi;
     string f = nopqr;`
```

how i  read this , plz help me,

Comment: USe split function and store into a array

Comment: @kaya ji i find many times but i donot find proper solution, thats y i put this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the split method:

```
String[] tokens = str.split(";")
```

for example:

```
String myString = "abc;def;ghi;jklm;nopqr";
String[] tokens = myString.split(";")
//tokens[0]="abc"
//tokens[1]="def"
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String string = "aaa;bbb";
String[] parts = string.split(";");
String part1 = parts[0]; //aaa
String part2 = parts[1];//bbb
```